# Meaning of the following notation for first order derivative in state space equation

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I was working on a problem about state-space representation, the context is of a first order differential equation that we try to linearize around a reference state vector and I came upon this notation :

$$S_{dot} = F(S,t) = F(S^*,t) + \frac {dF(t)}{dS(t)}|_{S^*} [S(t) - S^*(t)] + ... $$

Where S* is the reference state vector. The part that i don't understand is the derivative which is refered to as the first order derivative. To me it kind of looks like a Jacobian or something but I'm not sure. And I don't see how concretely you would calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dot{x} =f(x,t)$ be a state space model, the linearization around $x_R$ ($R$ for reference) is given by:

$$\Delta \dot{x} =f(x_R,t)+ \left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x_R}\Delta x,$$

in which $\Delta x = x - x_R$. And as you allready suspected $$\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x_R}$$

is the Jacobian evaluated at $x_R$.

For a second order system, this looks like

$$\dot{x}_1 = f_1(x,t)$$
$$\dot{x}_2 = f_2(x,t)$$

$$\Delta\dot{x}_1 = f_1(x_R,t)+ \left.\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}\right|_{x_1=x_{R1},x_2=x_{R2}}\Delta x_1  +\left.\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\right|_{x_1=x_{R1},x_2=x_{R2}}\Delta x_2$$

$$\Delta\dot{x}_2 = f_2(x_R,t)+\left.\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}\right|_{x_1=x_{R1},x_2=x_{R2}}\Delta x_1  +\left.\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}\right|_{x_1=x_{R1},x_2=x_{R2}}\Delta x_2$$

Comment: You forgot to add $f(x_R,t)$ (for equilibrium points we do have $f(x_R,t)=0$ but the question seems to indicate that this does not have to be case).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen: Could you elaborate what you mean? The $f(x_R,t)$ is incorporated in the condition $\Delta \dot{x} = \dot{x}-\dot{x}_R=\dot{x}-f(x_R,t)$.

Comment: No because $\dot{x}_R=0$ because $x_R$ is a constant. Also it might be worth mentioning that the terms stated in the question are basically the 0th and 1th terms of a Taylor series expansion.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thank you I was mixing two different ways of setting up the linearization.